# Javascript gradual opacity not working unless console is open

Tags: javascript

I'm having a very strange problem, I'm using a rather simple code to gradually fade in a div's child element, and the code works and all,  BUT here's the strange part is the code doesn't run properly unless I've got the dev console open. It just gets to the end sum of opacity. Had the same issue with Mozilla and Edge, but chrome worked properly without a console being opened.

basically: console open = gradual fadein, no console, same code just skips to the end sum of opacity

here's my code

```
function FadeIn(item){
    var ChildElement = item.firstElementChild;
    var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("sonum");
    var kestvus = tooltips.length;
    var x = 0;
    if(ChildElement.style.display == "none"){
        while (x < kestvus){
            if(tooltips[x].style.display == "block") {
                tooltips[x].style.display = "none";
                tooltips[x].style.opacity = 0;
            }
            x= x+1;
        }
        ChildElement.style.display = "block";
     
        for (var i = 0, a = 0;i <= 10000; i++ ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
            a = a + 0.0001;
            ChildElement.style.opacity = a;
            },50);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: all those setTimeouts will trigger after 50ms, they don't wait for each other

Comment: weird, but without those timeouts the fadein doesn't work even with the dev tools open

Comment: I'm surprised it fades ever

Comment: why not use [`transition`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) or [`animations`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)?

Comment: although using timeouts like this is an abuse, if you want all of them to happen in sequence, change the time from `50` to `50 * i`

Comment: great, that worked, changed the loop to increment the opacity by 0.1 10 times with the 50* i fix. but why is that considered abuse? Also on the transition and animation front, I honestly got confused on how to accomplish that so I thought js would be easier

Comment: Whilst I wouldn't necessarily call it abuse, you are trying to do in javascript what css does automatically - transitions.  The basic idea of transitions is that, if you apply a class name to an object and that class has been defined with a transition, the transition will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to test the behavior you're saying but it's probably just a way Chrome execute javascript for debugging or I don't know...

Anyway, I'd say that if you want to do it in javascript (although you should get into [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)) you replace that for loop with a setInterval().
I've removed that tooltip logic but you can add it back.

Here is how I'd fix yours.

```
function FadeIn(item){

    var ChildElement = item.firstElementChild;
    if(ChildElement.style.display == "none"){

        ChildElement.style.display = "block";

        let a = 0
        var fadeLoop= setInterval(function(){
            a = a + 0.01;
            ChildElement.style.opacity = a;
            if (a >= 1) clearInterval(fadeLoop)
        },50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a simple idea of how transitions work, have a look at this:

```js
function toggleClass() {
  const ele = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  ele.classList.toggle("show");
  ele.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:yellow;
}

#mydiv.hide {
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#mydiv.show {
  opacity:1;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleClass();">Toggle class</button>
<div id="mydiv" class="show">Some text</div>
```

As you can see, there's very little that needs to be set up - just two classes, one for opacity:0 and one for opacity:1.  The code simply switches between them and the transition instruction kicks in automatically.

Comment: Oh so that's how those work. I was pretty confused honestly how to make the animation run on the click of a div. Thanks a ton.

Comment: :D  It's one of those things that sounds complicated but is actually very easy to implement.   The simple rule is that a transition only kicks in when you apply the class to an object, so you need to have two classes defined - a "before" and "after" or a "show" and "hide", for example, and add the transition to one (for a simple fade in or fade out) or to both (a toggle fade in then out or vice versa)